# Multiply tensor lua

Tags: lua, torch

I'm new to lua,

Why the  below code does not work?

```
local data = torch.Tensor(100, 4)
--data tensor is read from file
local w = torch.Tensor(1, 4):zero()
local tmp = w * data[5]:t()
```

Comment: What is `data[5]:t()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[5]` is a 1-D tensor and [transpose](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor-t) only works for 2-D tensors. So you can use the [indexing](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor--dim1dim2--or--dim1sdim1e-dim2sdim2e-) operator as follow to obtain an extra dimension:

```
 -- matrix-matrix operation: result is a 1x1 tensor
 local tmp = w * data[{{5}}]:t()
```

Or alternatively [squeeze](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor-squeezedim) the first singleton dimension of `w`:

```
 -- dot prod between 1D tensors: result is a number
 local tmp = w:squeeze() * data[5]
```